# Passing NSString from one Tableviewcontroller to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have been searching and trying to work this out for a few hours. I know that I'm making a very simple mistake, I just don't know what it is!

I am trying to get the text that's entered into two different UITextFields and put them into a table of another TableViewController.

My NSLog is returning that my addGuestViewController is receiving the text input, but not transferring it into my guestlistViewController.

guestlistViewController.h

```
@interface guestlistViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSString *firstnameInput;
    NSString *lastnameInput;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstnameInput;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastnameInput;

@end
```

guestlistViewController.m

```
@synthesize firstnameInput;
@synthesize lastnameInput;
NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstnameInput, lastnameInput];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: fullname, nil];
NSLog(@"Their name is: "%@", fullname);
```

addGuestListViewController.h

```
@interface addGuestViewController : UITableViewController

@property NSString *firstnameInput;
@property NSString *lastnameInput;

@end
```

addGuestListViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    firstnameInput = firstname.text;
    lastnameInput = lastname.text;

    if (textField == firstname) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [lastname becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == lastname) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"done" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"Their name is: %@, %@", firstnameInput, lastnameInput);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If someone could inform me on what I'm doing wrong, it'd be a huge help as I'm fairly new to programming in Objective-C.

EDIT:

I was thinking that because I have my segue pointing to a navigation controller, it could be causing a problem, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the properties, firstnameInput and lastnameInput of your guestlistViewController -- In the textFieldShouldReturn: method, you're assigning values from the text fields to the addGuestListViewController's properties, not to the ones in guestlistViewController. You need to implement the method prepareForSegue:sender:, and in that method you get a reference to guestlistViewController with segue.destinationViewController. With that reference, you can set the values of the properties in that view controller. Something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     [(guestlistViewController *)[[(UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController viewControllers] lastObject] setFirstnameInput:firstnameInput];
     [(guestlistViewController *)[[(UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController viewControllers] lastObject] setLastnameInput:lastnameInput];
}
```

Comment: No, that's not correct. In that method, segue.destinationViewController will be gestlistViewController -- you shouldn't be doing any alloc init.

Comment: Your edited answer returns an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'guestlistViewController'". This is just a thought, but would my segue be causing the problem since I have it pointed to the navigation controller before guestlistViewController? I have it doing that so the menu bar and lower tab bar remain, but nonetheless...

Comment: I don't know if I spelled it correctly -- I used the spelling in your post, but the name of classes should be capitalized. Also, did you import the header for guestlistViewController into the addGuestListViewController.m file?

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem, and you should have mentioned that in your original post.

Comment: They're spelled right. However, I hadn't imported the guestlistViewController (just vice versa). Once I did import the addGuestListViewController.m, I got a SIGABRT "-[UINavigationController setFirstnameInput:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Yes, that's because of the navigation controller that you neglected to mention was the target of the segue.

Comment: I've edited my answer again. See if that works. One thing, I don't know how many view controllers you have in your navigation controller, so the lastObject reference might need to be changed to objectAtIndex:1 or some other number.

Comment: I ended up just getting rid of the Navigation Controller as I really didn't even need it (I said I was new, right?). What you had before worked perfectly. Thank you for your time!